# Ошибка при конвертации Dompdf

Tags: php, html

Подскажите, в чем может быть ошибка в библиотеке Dompdf, при использовании стандартного примера конвертации Html в pdf выдает следующее сообщение "Unable to stream pdf headers already sent".

Comment: а код где ваш? покажите что-нибудь

Comment: @МаксМаксимус ` // include autoloader
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

// instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml('hello world');

// (Optional) Setup the paper size and orientation
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

// Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();`

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка "Unable to stream pdf headers already sent" из-за того что у вас что-то попадает в поток перед pdf документом, сформированным библиотекой Dompdf. Посмотрите, чтоб не было никаких echo или передачи заголовков. Иначе работать не будет.